# How can I make a bootstrap navbar stay on top after scrolling down? (It's more complicated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the picture of my website header.
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmadN.jpg)

How can I make the blue navbar scroll smoothly to the top while i scroll down the page

(only the navbar, not the logo&social media stuff part)?

`position:fixed;` won't let the navbar move to the very top when I scroll down (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

```
   navbar {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Try setting the margin and padding of the navigation bar to 0.It should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Bootstrap, so you can use **Bootstrap Affix**: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

With the *data-spy*,  *data-offset-top* and *data-offset-bottom* properties you can add affix behavior and define when to toggle the pinning of an element.